# How can I implement multi threaded recursion in PHP?

Tags: php, recursion

I have a category tree in XML like

```
<cat name='cat_1' id='1'>

 <cat name='cat_2' id='2'>
   <cat name='cat_3' id='3'>

   </cat>
 </cat>

 <cat name='cat_4' id='4'>
   <cat name='cat_5' id='5'>

      <cat name='cat_6' id='6'>
        <cat name='cat_7' id='7'>

        </cat>
      </cat>
  </cat>  
 </cat>

</cat>
```

now I want to implement code such that I can travers this tree an find categories ids by the name i.e. If input is cat_6 than result should be 6;

What I have done

$xmlCatTree // is my simple xml object

```
class MyClass{   
 public function traverseForId($cat_name , $xmlCatTree )
      {

        if($xmlCatTree->attributes()->name == $cate_name)
            {
              return $xmlCatTree->attributes()->id;
            }
        if(count($item->children())>0){
        foreach($item->children() as $child)
        {
             return $this->traverseForId($cat_name,$child);
        } } 

      } 

}
```

It works perfectly for single branch i.e  child nodes of cat_2 will have correct results but if I search for cat_7 nothing will return. I thing It happens due to branched recursion. I want to know how to cop this.

Comment: Multi-threaded? What do you mean by that?

Comment: @vascowhite recursion in more than one branch.

Comment: @vascowhite in my code multiple branches are created through foreach loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, that you are using `SimpleXML`, thus I recommend to directly query the tree.

```
foreach ($xmlCatTree->xpath('//cat[@name=' . $cat_name . ']') as $node)
  return $node->attributes()->id;
}
return null;
```

This is even more elegant, because it directly reflects, what you are trying to achieve: Give me all the nodes with attribute "name" with the value "`$cat_name`".

Or (because it seems, that the ID is already part of the category name ;))

```
list($unusedThingy, $id) = array_pad(explode('_', $cat_name, 2), 2, null);
return $id;
```

But I guess thats not really, what you are looking for ;)

Comment: It's perfect had same suggestion by my colleague, but my motive of asking this question was to find out what actually happens in such threaded recursion I will accept this answer if will not find any other light on my point. Thanks For the Answer :)

Comment: +1 - but useful as it is, I avoid using `list()` and skipping parameters with emptys, because it looks like it *should* be a syntax error, and n00bs may come along and see this and think that you are allowed to skip *function* arguments with an empty (like you are in e.g. VBA) where in PHP you will get a syntax error, then you get questions on here about it which immediately get closed and downvoted and we scare off new SO members - it's a vicious circle. It's PHP's fault, not yours, but I feel one should try and use a horrible language in as nice (read: consistent) a way as possible.

Comment: @DaveRandom Sometimes I use `$_` as temporary "I don't really use it. Really!"-variable name, but I don't think it's PHPs fault, when "whoever" can't read error messages when omitting function arguments ;)

Comment: @KingCrunch Agreed that most questions here can be answered with RTFM/JFGI but unfortunately that's not about to change. I treat `list()` like `goto` and variable variables - yes you *can*, but for christ's sake, *don't*. I hate that PHP has "language constructs" that *look* like functions but in a very subtle way are not in fact functions, and `list()` particularly so. Since when does something that looks like a function belong on the left side of an assignment expression? Which PHP developer thought that was a good idea? (I'm not in any way having a pop at you here, by the way)

Comment: @DaveRandom OK, here I agree and now, that `array()` is gone, I hope `list()` will follow ;) As far as I know `list()` and `array()` are two of the oldest "constructs" in PHP at all, so I don't think it make sense to blame the one, who implemented it. It was an other time then :D And as far as I can see this both are the only two, that act this way.

Answer (score 1):

Your function check only first child, try to use my code:

```
public function traverseForId($cat_name, $xmlCatTree)
{
    if ($xmlCatTree->attributes()->name == $cat_name)
        return $xmlCatTree->attributes()->id;

    foreach ($xmlCatTree->children() as $child) {
        $res = $this->traverseForId($cat_name, $child);
        if($res)
            return $res;
    }
    return NULL;

}
```

Comment: This is what I have done so far, checking for the NULL response and killing the branches with no hope. There is no problem with it but I just don't feeling good about that. I have been achieved this by try and error but not have efficient understanding what is going on ..